# Turn on Do Not Disturb mode on all devices from one device

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, do-not-disturb

Has anyone found a way to turn on Do Not Disturb mode for every device from one.

Often times when I'm trying to work and people won't shut up I turn on DND mode on my MBP but then my iPhone will start dinging away. So I turn on DND mode there too. Then iPad starts up etc. This is an almost endless process. There's an additional 2 other Macs tied into my iCloud account. I've been tempted to just turn it off completely but it's about as handy as it is annoying.

Also find that when I need to turn DND mode off I forget on 1 device or more causing some annoyance if I actually need the notifications.

Ideally I'd like to be able to activate DND mode globally from my MBP.

I'm curious if anyone else has seen a possible solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

This now happens by default. Here is the Apple Documentation source, screenshot as well to anticipate link rot.

> When you use Focus on one device, the setting is automatically applied across your Apple devices that are signed in with the same Apple ID.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608

[image: Turn on focus]

Answer (score 1):

Make a shortcut home automation with that (and be sure that everywhere your logged in same apple id )

Comment: This answer is fortunately outdated now. See here for more good news: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/447999/160704

Comment: then when i posted it was up-to-date tho (and yes i still use ios 14)