# Is it possible to sync the Do Not Disturb mode between Mac and iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

So when I turn on the Do Not Disturb mode on a mac it would be active also on my iPhone?

Comment: [Similar question here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201499/turn-on-do-not-disturb-mode-on-all-devices-from-one-device?rq=1) but no answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now! As of iOS 14 or 15 I believe. See the [Demo](https://youtu.be/uBGLI8SPMD8).

***Explanation***

This question is a little old now (current accepted answer aged at approximately 6 years!) but in fact, this is now possible and is a built in feature of what are called "Focusses".

**Official Documentation from Apple**

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608

> When you use Focus on one device, the setting is automatically applied across your Apple devices that are signed in with the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately no, but this is something I would also greatly appreciate.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446971/160704